# Mysql three table join results empty set

Tags: mysql, sql, outer-join, right-join

Hello I have three tables that I have joined but it returns empty result even though there suppose to some result. Here is my sql

```
SELECT c.code,c.name, a.ltp as begning, b.ltp as enddate, d.interim_cash,d.interim_rec_date,
CAST(((b.ltp - a.ltp) / a.ltp * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as chng
FROM eod_stock a
JOIN eod_stock b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN company AS c
ON c.ID = a.company_id
RIGHT JOIN divident_info AS d
ON c.ID = d.company_id
WHERE a.entry_date = "2012-09-24"
AND b.entry_date = "2012-09-25"
AND d.interim_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25"
AND a.company_id IN (13, 2)
AND d.company_id IN (13,2);
```

The result i am expecting is like this:

```
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+
| code   | name            | begning | end    | chng   | interim_rec_date |interim_cash|
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+
| ABBANK | AB BANK LIMITED |  518.00 | 459.00 | -11.39 |2012-09-24        |10          |
| 1STICB | 1ST ICB M.F.    |  227.00 | 253.00 |  11.45 |                  |            |
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+--------+------------------+------------+
```

But I am getting empty set in my result is this because the second one interim info is 0? how can I get all info like above if row is empty then it could be blank but i need other info related to it.

Here are my table schema:

eod_stock:

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| company_id      | varchar(30)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| entry_date      | date             | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| entry_timestamp | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| open            | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| high            | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| low             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ltp             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| ycp             | decimal(16,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cse_price       | decimal(9,2)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| cse_volume      | decimal(18,2)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| total_trade     | int(30)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| total_volume    | int(30)          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| total_value     | decimal(18,4)    | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

divident Info:

```
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| divident_ID      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| company_id       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| year             | year(4)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| right_base       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| right_new        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| right_dec_date   | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| right_rec_date   | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| interim_cash     | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| interim_stock    | decimal(8,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| interim_dec_date | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| interim_rec_date | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| annual_cash      | decimal(6,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| annual_stock     | decimal(8,2) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| annual_dec_date  | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| annual_rec_date  | date         | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| update_time      | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Please can you help me to find out the result?

Comment: What about this "end" in your request which seems to be a misinterpreted..

Comment: in different query that end is not creating any problem but updated that yet no luck

Comment: Consider simplifying the problem to only the relevant columns and providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle for that, TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I got what i needed here is the query:

```
 SELECT c.code,c.name, a.ltp as begning, b.ltp as enddate, d.interim_cash,d.interim_rec_date,      d.annual_rec_date,d.annual_cash,
 CAST(((b.ltp - a.ltp) / a.ltp * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as chng
 FROM eod_stock AS a

 LEFT OUTER JOIN eod_stock AS b
 ON a.company_id = b.company_id

 LEFT OUTER JOIN company AS c
 ON c.ID = a.company_id

 LEFT OUTER JOIN dividend_info AS d
 ON c.ID = d.company_id AND d.interim_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25" AND       d.annual_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25"

 WHERE a.entry_date = "2013-09-24"
 AND b.entry_date = "2013-09-25"
 AND a.company_id IN (13, 2,4,5);
```

Thanks Gordon Linoff for bring me on the track i was messing up with the right join

Answer (score 1):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.code,c.name, a.ltp as begning, b.ltp as enddate, d.interim_cash,d.interim_rec_date,
       CAST(((b.ltp - a.ltp) / a.ltp * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as chng
FROM eod_stock a JOIN
     eod_stock b
     ON a.company_id = b.company_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
     company AS c
     ON c.ID = a.company_id RIGHT JOIN
     divident_info d
     ON c.ID = d.company_id
WHERE a.entry_date = "2012-09-24" AND
      b.entry_date = "2012-09-25" AND
      d.interim_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25" AND
      a.company_id IN (13, 2) AND
      d.company_id IN (13, 2);
```

Personally, I find it very hard to follow queries where `left join`s are mixed with `right join`s:  much easier to have a structure only using `left join`s so you can readily see which table drives the query.

In any case, your `where` clause is undoing the effects of the outer joins.  In addition to the conditions you have explicitly listed, you are also saying:

```
a.entry_date is not null and
b.entry_date is not null and
d.interim_rec_date is not null and
a.company_id is not null and
d.company_id is not null
```

It is really hard to say which of these conditions you need to eliminate to get the results you want.  What I can say is that some of these should go into the `on` clauses rather than the `where` clause.  That is the best solution.  You can also change the `where` to be something like this:

```
WHERE a.entry_date = "2012-09-24" AND
      b.entry_date = "2012-09-25" AND
      d.interim_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25" AND
      a.company_id IN (13, 2) AND
      d.company_id IN (13, 2) AND
      (a.entry_date is null  or a.company_id is null or b.entry_date is null)
```

However, you might want only one or two of those conditions.  Note the conditions on `d` should stay in the `where` clause because the `right outer join` is keeping all rows in `d`, so the would not be `NULL` (unless `NULL` in the original data).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT c.code,c.name, a.ltp as begning, b.ltp as enddate, 
d.interim_cash,d.interim_rec_date,
CAST(((b.ltp - a.ltp) / a.ltp * 100) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) as chng
FROM eod_stock a
JOIN eod_stock b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN company AS c
ON c.ID = a.company_id
RIGHT JOIN divident_info AS d
ON c.ID = d.company_id AND d.interim_rec_date BETWEEN "2012-09-24" AND "2012-09-25"
AND d.company_id IN (13,2)    
WHERE a.entry_date = "2012-09-24"
AND b.entry_date = "2012-09-25"
AND a.company_id IN (13, 2);
```

Comment: it leaves the other result empty. mean  company id returns no result